# Forcing order precedence (right associative)

Tags: java, operator-precedence

Forcing order precedence on left-associated operations comes pretty easily: 
`10 - 5 + 3` vs. `10 - (5 + 3)`

But, I was wondering if there was a way to force precedence like this with right-associative operators? I'm having a hard time figuring it out. 
Like, for example, if I was working in Java, could I force the precedence of something like the `++` or the `=` operators?

Comment: No, I don't believe it is possible to overload the precedence of operators in Java.  Use parentheses as you have already figured out.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen So, say I'm working with the operation "~-3" in Java. Are you saying it's not possible to force the precedence of this?

Comment: That's what I'm saying :-) ... use parentheses if you want to change the default behavior.

Comment: Seems interesting but I am not certain what you want to do.  Can you provide an example of the expression and the desired outcome?  Maybe edit your question to provide more detail.

Comment: @WJS I'm just curious if it's possible to force the order of a right-associative operator using parentheses. It's pretty easy to do it with the left-associative operators, I think. Say I have something like: "x = y = z". At the end, x would be equal to whatever value z was. Would it be possible to do something like "(x = y) = z" to alter how it is evaluated? If that makes any sense.

Comment: I was referring to your question regarding the ++ operator.  And ~-3 is already right associative.  The - is bound to the 3 as a unary operator.  Which is then complemented.  And this discussion is probably getting too long.  Again I suggest you edit your question and provide additional examples with values and show the desired outcomes you expect from right associativity.  Then you may get some answers explaining how to specifically accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, changing the evaluation order of right-associative operators works the same way as with left-associative operators.

When you have an expression of the form `a × b × c`, you can determine the evaluation order by specifying either, `(a × b) × c` or `a × (b × c)`, regardless of which was the default. The [JLS, §15.7.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7.3) states:

> The Java programming language respects the order of evaluation indicated explicitly by parentheses and implicitly by operator precedence.

However, the result of an assignment is a value and a value is not allowed to the left of an assignment operator, so `(a = b) = c` is always invalid. This differs from programming languages like C++ where an expression¹ could evaluate to an assignable reference.

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59070074/2711488), the precedence is given implicitly by the grammar of the Java programming language. Since the grammar of the assignment operator is already defined in a way that it doesn’t allow arbitrary expressions to the left of the operator, notably the braced expression is not supported at this place, an attempt to assign to a braced assignment would already get rejected by the parser².

Note that similarly, `a -> b -> c` is right-associative, but can’t be changed, as `(a -> b) -> c` is not a valid expression because the only valid thing to the left of `->` is a parameter list.

The only right-associative expression in Java, where changing the order would be meaningful, is the tertiary operator, as `a? b: c? d: e` gets evaluated as `a? b: (c? d: e)`, but can be changed to `(a? b: c)? d: e`, which would be valid if `b` and `c` evaluate to a `boolean` result.

For a combination of unary operators, you can’t change the evaluation order by inserting parentheses. If you have an expression of the form `op1 op2 value` but want `op2 op1 value` instead, just use the latter. A different thing would be, e.g. `- a - b`, for which `(- a) - b` and `- (a - b)` have a different meaning, but that’s another case where a binary operator is involved.

¹ other than those ending in a variable name or array index
² at least, it should. I just noticed that both, ecj and javac, contradict the specification and only reject it after parsing